# how can i run a linux process in the background and log the nohup output

Tags: linux, ubuntu

am trying to run a nohup process to be in the background. The process is firing successfully but for some reason its creating a nohup.out file in the location where I fire the process.

```
nohup bash -c "./manage.py celeryd -B -E -l DEBUG &> ../../logs/celeryd_beat.nohup &> ../../logs/celeryd_beat.err" &
```

Is there a way so i can make the nohup outputs into ../../logs/celeryd_beat.nohup?

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
nohup bash -c "./manage.py celeryd -B -E -l DEBUG > ../../logs/celeryd_beat.nohup 2> ../../logs/celeryd_beat.err" &
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, if you look at the man page for `nohup` it says

> To save output to FILE, use `nohup COMMAND > FILE'.

(at least that's on my system, though you should check to see if yours is the same). So something like

```
nohup bash -c "..." >../../logs/celeryd_beat.nohup
```

should work for you. (I omitted your command between the quotes, but you should of course actually include it when you do this)

**EDIT:** Actually, now that I noticed you are redirecting standard output and standard error of the Python script itself (for which you should be using `>` and `2>` if you want them to go to separate files - see Jim's answer), you may just want to discard the output of `nohup` itself, which shouldn't actually include anything. So in that case you can do

```
nohup bash -c "..." >/dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a feature of `nohup` to save output to `nohup.out` if you do not redirect it.  Since you appear to already be saving all the output you want, you can just add `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end, just before the final `&`.  (What's with the outer `bash -c`, though? It looks completely unnecessary to me.)